# How make time synchronization between android devices when lack access to GPS, GSM and Internet?

Tags: android, timestamp, intranet

I need to synchronize time between two or more android devices. But I don't need change local time, only knew different in time on different devices.

I cannot assume that devices have access to GPS or GMS or even to Internet. The connection is made in intranet by WIFI.

Is a API on Android which help me make this quick?

For connection I use Socket and ServerSocket classes.

Update: I search API which help me to exchange data about time and synchronize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

System.setCurrentTimeMilli() - this will change the system time and all apps / widgets which use the system time should then be updated.

Additionally you will need :

```
android.permission.SET_TIME
```

as a uses permission in the manifest.

As for the connection and communicating between the phones - I dont know what problem it is you are solving - but you could have a server socket on one phone - and sockets on the other - and use those to communicate.

Comment: Yes but I search API for exchange data about time rather than set time. But thx.

Comment: There will definitely not be an API for that - you will have to do that yourself - it wouldnt be hard to do though!